# Relation between two distributions expressed in terms of their CDFs

Tags: statistics, functions, probability-distributions, transformation

Not great at stats, and having trouble wrapping my mind around this.  Would love an explanation, not overly detailed, in plain english of what these transformations mean.

> The bias correction strategy assumes that the model discrepancies stay
>   constant in time [i.e., the relationship between the distributions of
>   $X_o$ and $X_m$ is the same as the relationship between the distributions of
>   $X_o′$ and $X_m′$ (Figs. 1a,b)]. This allows predictions of future
>   observables to be obtained by mapping from future model simulations,
>   $X_o′ = B(X_m′ )$, with a transfer function given by $B(X′_m) = F_o^{-1}[F_m(X_m′)]$, where $F_m( \cdot )$ is the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of $X_m$
>   and $F_o^{-1}( \cdot )$ is the inverse CDF (the “quantile function”) of $X_o$.

Image that goes along with it:

[image]

Mostly can't wrap my mind around this part:

> $B(X′_m) = F_o^{-1}[F_m(X_m′)]$, where $F_m( \cdot )$ is the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of $X_m $   and $F_o^{-1}( \cdot )$ is the inverse CDF (the “quantile function”) of $X_o$.

How do you apply a CDF from one variable to another, and then also apply the CDF to the result?  I thought these (the CDFs) were merely the characteristics of a variable, not functions that could be applied to another variable.

I should add, I understand there description, but not how their math/symbolation matches there description.

Much thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CDF is a function (which is what the letter F is for), and any reasonable function $\varphi$ can be applied to a random variable $X$, producing another random variable $\varphi(X)$. As a special case, applying the CDF of $X$ to $X$ itself results in a random variable uniformly distributed between $0$ and $1$, no matter what the original distribution was (as long as it was continuous). Another way to state this: $X = \varphi^{-1}(Z)$ where $Z$ is uniformly distributed between $)$ and $1$, and $\varphi$ is the CDF of $X$. This is essentially a restatement of what CDF is.

But here we are not really applying one CDF, but rather the composition $F_o^{-1}\circ F_m$, called the transfer function. What does this function tell us about the relation of $X_0$ and $X_m$? If $y=F_o^{-1}\circ F_m(x)$, then $F_o(y)=F_m(x)$, so the probability of $X_0\le y$ is the same as the probability of $X_m\le x$. In other words, this composition $F_o^{-1}\circ F_m(x)$ converts numbers from the range of $X_m$ to the range of $X_0$, so that the result of conversion is exactly the same percentile of $X_0$ as the original number was for $X_m$.

What good is this for us? Well, if we have another pair of variables $X_0'$ and $X_m'$, which we believe to be in the same relation as $X_0$ and $X_m$, we can use the transfer function to predict $X_0'$ based on $X_m'$. This is the idea of plugging $X_m'$ into the transfer function.

Comment: Great answer, thanks so much!!!